# How to order by a data table using a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a data table and it contains 7 rows .It has a sequence column ( 1 to 7) and each row has values from 1 to 7, I have a string that contains values  string sequence = (1,3,2,5,4,7,6)
I need to show the data table rows based on the sequence string .How to re order the data table values as per the string sequence ?

```
void RepopulateRowWiseDiscount()
    {
        var query = (from b in dsLoadData.Tables["DatasetLoadData"].AsEnumerable()
                        where b.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted
                        group b by new
                        {
                            PriceListDiscountPercentageAmount = b["PriceListDiscountAmount"],
                            Discount1 = b["Discount1"],
                            Discount2 = b["Discount2"],
                            Discount3 = b["Discount3"],
                            PriceListSchemaDiscount = b["PriceListSchemaDiscountAmount"],
                            DocumentDiscountAmount = b["DocumentDiscountAmount"],
                            PatientTypeDiscount = b["PatientTypeDiscountAmountxQty"]
                        } into g  
                        select new
                        {
                            PriceListDiscountPercentageAmount = g.Key.PriceListDiscountPercentageAmount,
                            Discount1 = g.Key.Discount1,
                            Discount2 = g.Key.Discount2,
                            Discount3 = g.Key.Discount3,
                            PriceListSchemaDiscount = g.Key.PriceListSchemaDiscount,
                            DocumentDiscountAmount = g.Key.DocumentDiscountAmount,
                            PatientTypeDiscount = g.Key.PatientTypeDiscount
                        });

        foreach (var Disc in query)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtSummary.NewRow();
            dr["SequenceNo"] = 1;
            dr["MainGridHeading"] = "PriceListDiscountAmount";
            dr["DiscountName"] = stringPriceListDiscountPercentageAmount;
            dr["DiscountAmount"] = Disc.PriceListDiscountPercentageAmount;
            dtSummary.Rows.Add(dr);

            DataRow dr1 = dtSummary.NewRow();
            dr1["SequenceNo"] = 2;
            dr1["MainGridHeading"] = "Discount1";
            dr1["DiscountName"] = stringPriceListDiscount_1;
            dr1["DiscountAmount"] = Disc.Discount1;
            dtSummary.Rows.Add(dr1);

            DataRow dr2 = dtSummary.NewRow();
            dr2["SequenceNo"] = 3;
            dr2["MainGridHeading"] = "Discount2";
            dr2["DiscountName"] = stringPriceListDiscount_2;
            dr2["DiscountAmount"] = Disc.Discount2;
            dtSummary.Rows.Add(dr2);

            DataRow dr3 = dtSummary.NewRow();
            dr3["SequenceNo"] = 4;
            dr3["MainGridHeading"] = "Discount3";
            dr3["DiscountName"] = stringPriceListDiscount_3;
            dr3["DiscountAmount"] = Disc.Discount3;
            dtSummary.Rows.Add(dr3);

            DataRow dr4 = dtSummary.NewRow();
            dr4["SequenceNo"] = 5;
            dr4["MainGridHeading"] = "PriceListSchemaDiscountAmount";
            dr4["DiscountName"] = stringPriceListSchemaDiscount;
            dr4["DiscountAmount"] = Disc.PriceListSchemaDiscount;
            dtSummary.Rows.Add(dr4);

            DataRow dr5 = dtSummary.NewRow();
            dr5["SequenceNo"] = 6;
            dr5["MainGridHeading"] = "DocumentDiscountAmount";
            dr5["DiscountName"] = "Document Discount";
            dr5["DiscountAmount"] = Disc.DocumentDiscountAmount;
            dtSummary.Rows.Add(dr5);

            DataRow dr6 = dtSummary.NewRow();
            dr6["SequenceNo"] = 7;
            dr6["MainGridHeading"] = "PatientTypeDiscountAmountxQty";
            dr6["DiscountName"] = stringPatientTypeDiscount;
            dr6["DiscountAmount"] = Disc.PatientTypeDiscount;
            dtSummary.Rows.Add(dr6);
        }

        IEnumerable<int> intSequence = stringRowWiseDiscountSequenceNumber.Split(',').Select(item => item[0]).Select(c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c));
        Dictionary<int, int> sequenceToIndex = intSequence.Select((s, i) => new { s, i }).ToDictionary(item => item.s, item => item.i);
        IEnumerable<DataRow> sortedRows = dtSummary.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => sequenceToIndex[r.Field<int>("SequenceNo")]);

        fpsRowWiseDiscount.ActiveSheet.RowCount = 0;
        fpsRowWiseDiscount.SuspendLayout();
        fpsRowWiseDiscount.DataSource = dtSummary;
        fpsRowWiseDiscount.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

This is my code

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
using System.Data;
...
const string stringSequence = "1,3,2,5,4,7,6";

IEnumerable<int> intSequence = 
    stringSequence.Split(',').Select(item => item[0])
                  .Select(c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c));

Dictionary<int, int> sequenceToIndex = 
    intSequence.Select((s, i) => new { s, i})
               .ToDictionary(item => item.s, item => item.i);

 IEnumerable<DataRow> sortedRows = 
     table.AsEnumerable()
          .OrderBy(r => sequenceToIndex[r.Field<int>("Sequence")]);

 DataTable sortedDataTable = sortedRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

[Link to Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qO6g8e)

Comment: `fpsRowWiseDiscount.DataSource = dtSummary;` you're still binding to the old table, add `DataTable sortedDataTable = sortedRows.CopyToDataTable();` and then `fpsRowWiseDiscount.DataSource = sortedDataTable;`

Comment: @Agnes What is the exact error message? Side note: you have to realize this site is just a help site for people having programming issues. I think I've answered your question, maybe more than I should, it takes time to build a working example (fiddle)... and I have limited time to help people on this site, and no obligation whatsoever to answer your questions in the hour.